# JFrame not showing (full)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I just installed `JFrame` and it seems to only shows a fraction of the form design, any fix to show the full form design?

Frame first opened:

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I believe you mean that you installed [WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/). Your screen capture looks fine to me. Are you saying that something is missing from the image in your question?